# Rails CSRF issue on receiving POST request from API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

I am working on Rails application which interacts with the API. Now there is a step that the API will send the POST request to the application and I tried saving the returned data to the database. But it looks like the application does not accept the data and return 422 : Unprocessable Entity

Here is the error message from the log file

```
W, [2016-02-29T12:21:54.865291 #22727]  WARN -- : Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
I, [2016-02-29T12:21:54.865839 #22727]  INFO -- : Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
F, [2016-02-29T12:21:54.870852 #22727] FATAL -- :
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
 actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:181:in `handle_unverified_request'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:209:in `handle_unverified_request'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:204:in `verify_authenticity_token'
```

I also tried disabling the CSRF

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

end
```

But it still doesn't work.

Please help me get through this. I have been struggling with this issue for three days.

Comment: `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
```